# Despite a condition for no equality the string is being added to the ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am splitting my `direcList` into two sublists `firstDirec` and `secondtDirec` when a speciefic string `New direction` was found.

Then I am filtering particular strings out of the lists by not adding them to the new `ArrayList`s  `timeListFirst and timeListSecond`. Everything  works fine for the `firstDirec`, and the elements are not being added to the `timeListFirst`, but I am facing a problem with the `secondtDirec` list at this postion:

```
if (!(mergeLine.equals(otherDirection))
```

since here at this position `mergeLine` is equal to`"Ravensbusch"` and so is  `otherDirection`. Despite this fact this string is being added to the `timeListSecond`. Can someone explain me my mistake?

**mergeLine value:**

[image]

**otherDirection value:**

[image]

```
        for (String keyLine : direcList) {
            if (keyLine.startsWith("New direction")) {
                int index = direcList.indexOf(keyLine);
                // direcArray.remove(index);
                List<String> firstDirec = direcList.subList(0, index);
                List<String> secondtDirec = direcList.subList(index,
                        direcList.size() - 1); // This part wih New
                                                // Direction.

                ArrayList<String> timeListFirst = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String mergeLine : firstDirec) {
                    if (!(mergeLine.equals(direction))
                            && !(mergeLine.equals(route))
                            && !(mergeLine.equals(day))) {
                        timeListFirst.add(mergeLine);

                    }
                }

                ArrayList<String> timeListSecond = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String mergeLine : secondtDirec) {
                    if (!(mergeLine.equals(otherDirection))
                            && !(mergeLine.equals(route))
                            && !(mergeLine.equals(day))
                            && !(mergeLine.equals("New direction"))) {
                        timeListSecond.add(mergeLine);

                    }
                }
```

Comment: So, if you now hit f6.......is it going to the line timeListSecond.add(mergeLine);??Try printing mergeLine+"-"+otherDirection before timeListSecond.add(mergeLine);
It is possible that debugger is using some cached value.

Comment: Yeah, step through with the debugger and make sure it's actually calling timeListSecond.add(mergeLine) directly after that point. If mergeLine and otherDirection actually have the same value, then the .add() method shouldn't be called for that particular value.

Comment: @Ouney: when I hit F6 it gos to `timeListSecond.add(mergeLine);`

Comment: print the values as i have mentioned in above comment. We shall see then :)

Comment: I have printed them and I am getting `mergeLine value: Ravensbusch - otherDirection value: Ravensbusch `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `otherDirection`'s value has a space at the end of it, therefore they are not equal and since there's a `!` in there, the entire expression is `true`.

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds... this is the right answer.

Comment: Good work, maybe edit your answer so you can specify the *value* of `otherDirection` has a space. (E.g. "Ravenbusch" has the space)

Comment: ham but when I do the following inside the for loop before the if statement nothing changes `mergeLine = mergeLine.trim();`

Comment: @TheBook the space is in `otherDirection`, not in `mergeLine`.